# How to get an user's session key out of a Token?

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a token with offline_access as special perms and i would like to know how to obtain the session key from that token (if required also using the appid, apikey and appsecret).

Is this even possible? If yes, how?

Comment: can you elaborate more? what do you mean by the session key? and why do you need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the PHP SDK you can call `$facebook->getSession()` and a few other functions. You can check it [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/)